# git rebase of three already merged branches into one?

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have these three branches that looks something like this:

```
A1--A2----A3--...--An----AB1--AB2--..--ABn--ABC
     \  \                /                  /
      \  C1-------------+------------------/ 
      B1--B2--...--Bn--/ (B merges to A)
```

I want to rebase them into single branch. How would you advise me to do it? The order of commits if those of C precede the As or or Bs - Cs does not much matter.

Comment: Was there a particular problem when you tried to do it? Simply something like `git rebase A1` should work as far as I can tell.

Comment: @mkrieger1, I haven't tried to do it as I am not very good to git and I am afraid to messing it up somehow... but ok, I'll try your advice, thanks!